# escape character for '@' -- JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm making a batch insert to MySQL table:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2) values("aa@gmail.com", "f2 value"), ("cc@gmail.com", "another f2 here");
```

giving error to the character '@' in the value String:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into buyers (field1, field2) values ('aa@' at line 1
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)

How can i get around this - is there some kind of escape charactr for JDBC to work this?

Note: I'm aware of JDBC-batch execution. I'm looking for a solution for the above - if any:

```
pStat.addBatch();
pStat.executeBatch();
```

TIA.

**Further note:** The above insert query runs fine directly on MySQL without JDBC in between. Also note: this isn't an issue when JDBC itself sets up the parameter with `pStat.getString("aa@gmail.com");` -- thus the batch execn is a solution.

Comment: Is the error in the insert itself? Have you tried brackets?

Comment: @DanielMarcus pls see "Further note." thx for the comment.

Comment: Thanks @xavierz that makes it a jdbc issue not a sql one

Comment: Does it help to use single quotes instead of double quotes: `values('aa@gmail.com', 'f2 value')`, ...?

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt no - same error.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J and which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: you intend to perform that query, but... what's the actual code you're using to try and do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the error message is  indicating a problem with the '@' at sign character.

MySQL syntax error "right syntax to use near" usually points to the *first* token where the problem is encountered.  In this case, it looks like MySQL is objecting to `INSERT`.

> ... near '`insert into buyers (field1, field2) values ('aa@`' at line 1 at

I suspect that there is something before that `insert` in the SQL text, and MySQL is seeing multiple statements. That's just a guess, we're not seeing the actual code.

I recommend displaying the actual contents of the SQL text, before it's executed or prepared.

Comment: then how come it's running fine on SQL scrapbook. i'm printing the query to console - copy/pasting to scrapbook to run.

Comment: besides-- the line doesn't end there at '@'.

Comment: @xavierz: I can't explain the behavior that you are observing; and it's not possible for me to reproduce the behavior. What I'm suggesting is that you are barking up the wrong tree in terms of JDBC and the '@' character. It should be fairly straightforward to test with field1 values that don't include the '@' character.

Comment: @xavierz: my suspicion is that there is more than one SQL statement in the query. We would expect this behavior if the SQL text was `INSERT INTO sometable ( ... ) VALUES (...),(...); insert into buyers ...`  MySQL would flag an error at the second insert, because that's a second *statement*. It's not allowed to run more than one SQL statement in a query.  (Again, I'm just guessing, because there is no code shown.)

Comment: If the problem is with the `@` at sign character in the statement, I don't think that's a JDBC issue. At least, I've never encountered that issue before. I suspect that it's something else that's munging the string, before the string gets passed to JDBC.(Again, without seeing the actual code that's being executed, we're just guessing.)

Answer (score 3):

Try using PreparedStatement. It resolves special characters automatically and avoids sql-injection.

```
String queryStr = "insert into table1 (field1, field2) values(?, ?);"
try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "aa@gmail.com");
    preparedStatement.setString(2, "f2 value");
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // Error
} finally {
    if (preparedStatement != null) {
        preparedStatement.close();
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

More examples: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2) 
  values('aa@gmail.com', 'f2 value'), ('cc@gmail.com', 'another f2 here');
```

Comment: Best practice for SQL is to use single quotes around string literals, but MySQL does allow for double quotes around string literals if `ANSI_QUOTES` is not included in `sql_mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UTF-8 code for special characters when running from Java. UTF-8 code for `@` is `\u0040`:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2) values("aa\u0040gmail.com", "f2 value"), ("cc\u0040gmail.com", "another f2 here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Was doing two queries separated by `;` in one. 
all resolved. 
nothing wrong with `@`.

Thanks for the insightful comments&answers.